# Swift 4.1 codable adoption for array to key = value (key contains a value)

Tags: swift, swift4

How can I use the Swift Codable protocol to decode/encode data that is stored inside Swift as an array of objects (with only 2 values) into a (JSON or other type of data representation; should not matter) key = value structure like this:

[image]

As you can see its a `timestamp = value` notation structure (I have no issue regarding formatting of timestamps thats ok)

(I know that there have been questions answered before about data stored in keys, however my questions is different because its specific for arrays of objects with only 2 values transcoded in a flat key = value structure).

Here is my code it deals with 2 objects:

`MetricResult` = contains a timestamp and a value of a measurement

`MetricResults` = contains a array of the MetricResult that should be properly encoded.

I managed to encode already for `MetricResult`, but when reading I don't know how to handle th e variable keys that contain actually data themselves.

```
struct MetricResult : Codable {
    var date   = Date()
    var result = Int(0)

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: Date.self)
        try container.encode(result, forKey: date)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        //how do deal with variable key name here??
    }
}

struct MetricResults: Codable {

    var results = [MetricResult]()

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        //how do deal with variable key name here??
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        //how do deal with variable key name here??
    }
}

extension Date: CodingKey {

    //MARK: - CodingKey compliance

    public init?(intValue: Int)       {
        return nil
    }

    public init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.init(stringFirebase: stringValue)
    }

    public var intValue: Int?{
        return nil
    }

    public var stringValue: String {
        return stringFirebase()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close; you've already worked out the trickiest part, which is how to make Date into a CodingKey (be sure to mark this `private`; it's possible other parts of the system will also want to use Date as a CodingKey in another way).

The main problem is that in this specification, MetricResult cannot itself be Codable. You can't encode just "a key value pair." That can only be encoded as part of something (i.e. a dictionary). All the encoding/decoding has to be done by MetricResults this way:

```
extension MetricResults: Codable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: Date.self)
        for result in results {
            try container.encode(result.result, forKey: result.date)
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Date.self)
        for date in container.allKeys {
            let result = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: date)
            results.append(MetricResult(date: date, result: result))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works a charm! I missed the availability of the allKeys. Thanks for the great answer Rob.